# How to click a link with the target attribute removed in PlayWright

Tags: playwright-test

I found this solution in another thread but it doesn't explain how to click the element.
I come from a Cypress background where you would just chain .click() or save as an alias and call it later or use a callback.

This is the snippet:
**await page.$eval('a:text("the link")', el => el.removeAttribute('target'));**

I am trying to remove the target attribute and then click the link so that a new page does not get opened.
Any help would be much appreciated.